# C# and Java how to convert bytes for stream

Tags: java, c#, sockets, byte

I made few attempts at sending data from C# UDP server to Java client with no luck. I know that there is difference between bytes in Java and C# however do not fully understand how to implement it. Any help would be great.

Below is my C# code:

```
TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
int secondsSinceEpoch = (int)t.TotalSeconds;
{
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    IPAddress UDP_local_add = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

    IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(UDP_local_add, 37);

    UdpClient UDPSocket = new UdpClient(endpoint);




    Console.WriteLine("UDP Server awaiting connections...");

    IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(UDP_local_add, 0);



    data = UDPSocket.Receive(ref sender);

    Console.WriteLine("Message received from {0}:", sender.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));

    data =System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secondsSinceEpoch.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine(secondsSinceEpoch);
    int converted = DecodeInt32(data);
    Console.WriteLine(converted);



    UDPSocket.Send(data, data.Length, sender);


    UDPSocket.Close();

}
```

and below is Java client code:

```
public class TimeUDPClient {
private static final int PORT_TIME = 37;
private static final String QUERY = "Ktora godzina?";
private static final int LINELEN = 5;
private static final long UNIXEPOCH = 2208988800L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[LINELEN];
        DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(QUERY.getBytes(), 0,
                QUERY.length(), InetAddress.getByName(args[0]), PORT_TIME);
        sock.send(dp);
        dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, LINELEN);
        sock.receive(dp);
        long time = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            time *= 256;
            time += (buffer[i] & 255);
        }
        time -= UNIXEPOCH;
        time *= 1000;
        Date d = new Date(time);
        System.out.println(d);
        sock.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see the port number allocation for the java server it will take a random one that is allocated by the system.

Comment: Added full stop to close the statement that makes statement easier to read and understood. Casing improved for cosistency e.g. UDP, Java (not java).